# How to enable server-wide translation?

Tags: django, translation

I am trying to force the translation of a website to German (without hard-coding the strings in German). I want German whatever the language code send by the client's browser is.

In my `settings.py`:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/path_to_my_app/locale',
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-de'
USE_I18N = True
```

There is nothing special in the installed apps and middlewares:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'my_project',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

I have generated relevant `django.po` and `django.mo` files in `/path_to_my_app/locale/de-de/LC_MESSAGES/`.

But my strings are not translated when using `ugettext()`. I also see this in the website shell:

```
In [1]: from django.utils.translation import get_language

In [2]: get_language()
Out[2]: u'en-us'
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after several hours of attempts...

In `settings.py`:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-de'
USE_I18N = True
```

(There is no need to set `LOCALE_PATHS`.)

Then, generate the relevant `django.po` and `django.mo` files in `/path_to_my_app/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/`. **Note the use of "de" here rather than "de-de".**

This makes me wonder how one can generate language variations across a country in Django...